# What points to be used for Drawing Hexagonal Shaped Button

Tags: c#, winforms

Using below code I am able to draw arrow shaped button(shown below) ,but I want to draw hexagone(shown below as result image) ,so that I can use png image of size 175x154 as button image ,What Points I need to use to draw this ? and i need to to draw 6 such buttons ,how do i achieve this ?

[image]

```
private void Parent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Define the points in the polygonal path.
    Point[] pts = {
        new Point( 20,  60),
        new Point(140,  60),
        new Point(140,  20),
        new Point(220, 100),
        new Point(140, 180),
        new Point(140, 140),
        new Point( 20, 140)
    };

    // Make the GraphicsPath.
    GraphicsPath polygon_path = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Winding);
    polygon_path.AddPolygon(pts);

    // Convert the GraphicsPath into a Region.
    Region polygon_region = new Region(polygon_path);

    // Constrain the button to the region.
    btnExam.Region = polygon_region;

    // Make the button big enough to hold the whole region.
    btnExam.SetBounds(
        btnExam.Location.X,
        btnExam.Location.Y,
        pts[3].X + 5, pts[4].Y + 5);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input should be a `Rectangle` which contains the `Hexagonal shape`, from that input we will calculate the `Points` for your `Hexagonal shape`, something like this:

```
public Point[] GetPoints(Rectangle container){
  Point[] points = new Point[6];
  int half = container.Height / 2;
  int quart = container.Width/4;
  points[0] = new Point(container.Left + quart, container.Top);
  points[1] = new Point(container.Right - quart, container.Top);
  points[2] = new Point(container.Right, container.Top + half);
  points[3] = new Point(container.Right - quart, container.Bottom);
  points[4] = new Point(container.Left + quart, container.Bottom);
  points[5] = new Point(container.Left, container.Top + half);
  return points;
}
private void Parent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //This should be placed first
  // Make the button big enough to hold the whole region.
  btnExam.SetBounds( btnExam.Location.X, btnExam.Location.Y, 100, 100);

  // Make the GraphicsPath.
  GraphicsPath polygon_path = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Winding);
  polygon_path.AddPolygon(GetPoints(btnExam.ClientRectangle));

  // Convert the GraphicsPath into a Region.
  Region polygon_region = new Region(polygon_path);

  // Constrain the button to the region.
  btnExam.Region = polygon_region;
}
```

You should **update the Region** whenever your `btnExam`'s Size changes, so you should define some method called `UpdateRegion` and call it in a `SizeChanged` event handler:

```
private void UpdateRegion(){
  GraphicsPath polygon_path = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Winding);
  polygon_path.AddPolygon(GetPoints(btnExam.ClientRectangle));
  btnExam.Region = new Region(polygon_path);
}
//SizeChanged event handler for your btnExam
private void btnExam_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
  UpdateRegion();
}
//Then you just need to change the size of your btnExam in Parent_Load
private void Parent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //The button should be square
  btnExam.SetBounds( btnExam.Location.X, btnExam.Location.Y, 100, 100); 
}
```

Comment: @Durga see my update. Note that, my code is for a `Square button`, if you would like a Button of any Rectangle, please let me know, I'll modify the code a little in the `GetPoints` method.

Comment: by using your solution I am getting above images ,but upper two slided ages are not coming properly ,can those be corrected and background white space,and I am not getting ,why the btnexam size will change ,you mean if i need to change size right?

Comment: @Durga not clear on what you mean by `two slided ages ...`, for the size change of your button, of course adding code to a `SizeChanged` event handler is better because if you want to change the size of your Button, the `Region` will be updated accordingly for you. Changing the size can be done **unexpectedly** in some case and your code won't be broken in that case.

Comment: Okay I got it now ,but as u said `//The button should be square` I am using this `175 x 154` size  as per my image size so is it fine

Comment: @Durga it's OK with a little modification in the `GetPoints`, update the `half` to `container.Height/2`

Comment: its same only for `half` in `GetPoints`

Comment: @Durga what do you mean? The old code set `half` to `container.Width/2`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39739/discussion-between-durga-and-king-king)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
var xDisp = 10;

var yDisp = 10;

var length = 10;

var ls32 = (int)(length * Math.Sqrt(3) / 2.0);

var half = (int)(length / 2.0);

var points = new[] 
{
    new Point(xDisp + length,   yDisp),
    new Point(xDisp + half,     yDisp + ls32),
    new Point(xDisp - half,     yDisp + ls32),
    new Point(xDisp - length,   yDisp),
    new Point(xDisp - half,     yDisp - ls32),
    new Point(xDisp + half,     yDisp - ls32)
};
```