# Drawing hexagon in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, polygon, shapes

I want to build a hexagon-shaped button. Here's the code I've got.

```
Dim p(5) As Point
            Dim v As Integer = CInt(Me.Width / 2 * Math.Sin(30 * Math.PI / 180))
            p(0) = New Point(Me.Width \ 2, 0)
            p(1) = New Point(Me.Width, v)
            p(2) = New Point(Me.Width, Me.Height - v)
            p(3) = New Point(Me.Width \ 2, Me.Height)
            p(4) = New Point(0, Me.Height - v)
            p(5) = New Point(0, v)
```

Unfortunately, it appears hexagon with the point at the top. What I want is a hexagon with horizontal line at the top.

Thanks!

Comment: seems like it needs 7 points with the last point equal to the first

Comment: nothing happens when i did that :(

Comment: Does moving the last point to first and renumbering fix it?

Comment: no @MrGadget, i already tried that, but does not fix it

Comment: Does this help? [What points to be used for Drawing Hexagonal Shaped Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513647/what-points-to-be-used-for-drawing-hexagonal-shaped-button)

Comment: thanks for the info @MrGadget but it does not help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just swap x and y coordinates, which effectively mirrors the shape at the system's diagonal. And adapt the scaling to `Width` and `Height` accordingly:

```
Dim v As Integer = CInt(Me.Height/ 2 * Math.Sin(30 * Math.PI / 180))
p(0) = New Point(0, Me.Height\ 2)
p(1) = New Point(v, Me.Height)
p(2) = New Point(Me.Width- v, Me.Height)
p(3) = New Point(Me.Width, Me.Height\ 2)
p(4) = New Point(Me.Width - v, 0)
p(5) = New Point(v, 0)
```

Be aware that this reverses the point order. If your processing method relies on that, you may need to re-order the points.