# vb.net custom buttons

Tags: vb.net, winforms, custom-controls

I am looking to make a hexagon looking button with a neon glow.
I am using visual studio windows forms app in VB. I used this because of the internal SQL database that will be leveraged by the program I am trying to make.

What I have for the button so far is this:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class Button_Hexagon
    Inherits Button

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(pevent As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim grpath As GraphicsPath = New GraphicsPath()
        Dim v As Integer = CInt(Me.Height / 2 * Math.Sin(30 * Math.PI / 180))

        Dim hexagonPoints(5) As Point

        hexagonPoints(0) = New Point(0, Me.Height \ 2)
        hexagonPoints(1) = New Point(v, Me.Height)
        hexagonPoints(2) = New Point(Me.Width - v, Me.Height)
        hexagonPoints(3) = New Point(Me.Width, Me.Height \ 2)
        hexagonPoints(4) = New Point(Me.Width - v, 0)
        hexagonPoints(5) = New Point(v, 0)


        grpath.AddPolygon(hexagonPoints)
        Me.Region = New Region(grpath)
        MyBase.OnPaint(pevent)
   End Sub
End Class
```

This creates a horizontal hexagon a vertical would be better but I just cannot figure out how to get it to glow or be a specific color I am looking for.

[image: Horizontal Hexagon]
[image: What I am trying to emulate]

[image: What I am trying to emulate 1]

Comment: What's a horizontal vs vertical hexagon?  Maybe update you question with a pic of the desired look?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the `Region` way, then don't set it in `OnPaint` method. Override the `OnSizeChanged` to do so. For the glow part, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39049068/14171304) if you mean something like that. Do some reading about the `PathGradientBrush` for better glow effect.

Comment: @Hursey I added two pictures. The first on is a horizontal hexagon I would like the tip up and the second and third are me trying the create Neon effect.

Comment: in my opinion, don't use buttons. Two ways to achieve that: 1. Use a full picture as background with all hexagon already draw and inside each "button" add a label with a good size with the icon, you'll still have the click event. OR 2. Create each hexagon as image and use the .top and .left and .BringToFront to fit them.

Comment: Agree with Miguel on the image, but still possible to do via button.  Perhaps this might be of some use to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570607/drawing-hexagon-in-vb-net where asking for the exact opposite of you.